# Smart card Mifare 1k keys

Tags: smartcard, mifare

Following some example I can read all blocks of sector 0 of a Mifare 1K card with the following commands:

- Load Authentication Keys
- Authentication
- Read Binary Blocks

For the first command I used a key of FF FF FF FF FF FF.
When I try to read block 4 (sector 1) I get an access denied error.
I suppose it is due to the fact that sector has a non default key. Is it correct ?

I'm not familiar with smart cards, the one I'm testing is for logging access to workplace, I (erroneously ?) thought it was as simple as a single read. All I need is the 6 digit code stamped on the card. I now suspect I have to know the key before accessing the information on the card.

Besides I thought there was a standard for Mifare 1K **adpu**.

According to documentation on internet the error condition is `Sw1 = 0x63` but according to my specific reader manual (**AccessIs ATR210**) it is `Sw1 = 0x69`. There are major differences in the adpu command too and it is confusing for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mifare and smart cards are different, only the latter understand APDUs. For the former the reader translates a pseudo-APDU to the respective command, therefore the reader or  its driver may require different bytes.

If the card you describe is used for a real world application, then a key different from the default is the very minimum one has to do to maintain the low MIFARE classic security. Besides a different value, the read access may not be possible using key A at all, see the [data sheet](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MF1S50YYX_V1.pdf), section 8.7.2.

I have no idea, what is stamped on your card, but 6 digits are less than the key value, which requires 6 bytes. Just the key value(s), i. e. for key A and B will allow you to access everything possibly restricted by the configured access bits.

Comment: Just to clarify the 6 digit code stamped on the card. Every employee has his own badge (Mifare 1K) with a different 6 digit code printed on it. I expect the same code is written inside some block in the card and I'm looking for it, but I don't know where and above all I don't know the key. The final goal would be to authenticate the same employee on our system using his original badge instead of giving him a second badge.

Comment: I would tend to assume, that the number is a sort of bookkeeping number of the IT department, so they can re-route lost and found cards. I fail to see, how it could be a PIN or how to acconmplish a two-factor authorization if the "something you know" part is short-circuited by printing it on the "something you have". Or how do you have to use the printed number in your system?