# Mifare Standard 1K - 6D00 for external authentication APDU

Tags: windows-ce, smartcard, apdu, mifare

External Authentication:
**FF 82 20 00 06 FF FF FF FF FF FF**

What is the correct procedure to run **External Authentication**? Do we need to run **Get Challenge** before **External Authentication**?

If I send the apdu of external authentication to OMNIKEY smart card reader, it will return me **9000** which mean success.

But If I do the same step with Workabout Pro4 and it return **6D00**?

**6D00** is instruction code is not supported or invalid, but it was working with Omnikey smart card reader. How to solve this problem?

**FYI: Read UID APDU Command is working on both devices: FF CA 00 00 00**

I have tried many different ways but none is working.

1. Changing the shared_mode while connect card[Exclusive, Shared]
2. Lock the thread for specific process
3. Put the thread to wait for few seconds before sending APDU
4. Send Get Challenge apdu before external authentication but failed

Comment: Mifare Classic cards are no smart cards, they understand neither Get Challenge nor External Authenticate. You may start with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56539253/1435475) to a related question for researching the differences and you have to decide whether Mifare Classic is really sufficient for what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I believe Mifare card is the smart card and it uses ISO/IEC 14443 Type A 13.56 MHz contactless smart card standard- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIFARE

Comment: Thanks for the reply! sorry that I don't understand the answer you posted, since the external authenticate command is working for me - https://www.acs.com.hk/en/download-manual/6402/API-ACR1252U-1.12.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself.

There are two ***Load Authentication Keys*** APDU commands:

1. **FF 82 20 00 06 FF FF FF FF FF FF** (*Obsolete*)
2. **FF 86 00 00 05 01 00 [Block Number] [Key Type] [Key Number]**

Use the second APDU command to do Load Authentication Keys then read/write the Mifare card content.

Comment: The command you found to work is not *EXTERNAL AUTHENTICATE* but *Load Authentication Keys*. It is not understood by the MIFARE card, but translated by the reader.