# ACR122u/Python3/smartcard lib how to read blocks

Tags: python-3.x, smartcard, rfid, mifare

I'm trying to read blocks from a Mifare 1K token by using smartcard python3 lib, but i'm not getting data.
I'm using ACR122u-A9.

```
import smartcard
from smartcard.util import toHexString

COMMAND = [0xFF, 0xCA, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00]
READ_16_BINARY_BLOCKS = [0xFF,0xB0,0x00,0x04,0x10]

sprotocol = smartcard.scard.SCARD_PROTOCOL_T1

reader = smartcard.System.readers()

conn =  reader[0].createConnection()
conn.connect()
result, sw1, sw2 = conn.transmit(COMMAND,protocol = sprotocol)
if (sw1, sw2) == (0x90, 0x0):
    print("The operation completed successfully.")
    #AUTHENTICATE = [0xFF, 0x88, 0x00, BLOCK_NUMBER, 0x60, 0x00]
    AUTHENTICATE = [0xFF, 0x88, 0x00, 0x01, 0x60, 0x00] #Authenticate block 1
    response = conn.transmit(AUTHENTICATE)
    print(response)
    if response[1] == 144:
        print("Authenticated successfully")
        value, sw1,sw2 = conn.transmit(READ_16_BINARY_BLOCKS) #read block 1
        print(value,sw1,sw1)
```

But the output is always:

> output1: The operation completed successfully.
>
> output2: ([], 144, 0)
>
> output3: Authenticated successfully
>
> output4: [] 99 99

The last output should give me a list of hex data, but i'm not getting anything, even tried to read block 0x00, same thing.

Update---
I was able to read block 4~7, which I believe that is sector 1, can't read others sectors.

Comment: The first sentence of your question should have contained, which card/token you are talking about.

Comment: What do you mean with which card? I'm trying to learn, sorry if my question is not clear enough. All I know is that is MIFARE Classic 1K, the hardware is a ACR122u-A9 and the equipment is new...

Comment: I suggest you revise your question. The part *the output is always...* seems no longer to hold after your update. Your last statement prints sw1 twice instead of sw1, sw2. Is the mifare token known to still be in factory state? Otherwise the keys may no longer have default values and you are simply getting an error due to wrong key. YOur authenticate command seems not to match the one from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58318802/1435475).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @guidot , I was doing all wrong, I need to load the key first, then authenticate the sector and finally read the sector blocks

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to read the sectors/blocks, i'm not sure if it's the right way, but it is working just fine with key A.

```
import smartcard
from smartcard.util import toHexString
import time

reader = smartcard.System.readers()
if not reader:
    print("No readers")
else:
    conn =  reader[0].createConnection()
    conn.connect()
    #[0xFF, 0x82, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06,KEY(6 bytes)]
    LOADKEY = [0xFF, 0x82, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06,255,255,255,255,255,255]
    response = conn.transmit(LOADKEY)
    if response[1] == 144:
        print("Key A loaded successfully")
        time.sleep(2)
        #auth block
        #[0xFF, 0x86, 0x00, 0x00, 0x05, 0x01, 0x00, BLOCK, KEY-TYPE, 0x00]
        COMMAND = [0xFF, 0x86, 0x00, 0x00, 0x05, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x60, 0x00]
        response = conn.transmit(COMMAND)
        print(response)
        time.sleep(2)
        #[0xFF, 0xB0, 0x00, BLOCK-NUMBER, 0x10]
        read = [0xFF, 0xB0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x10] #Read block 0
        data, sw1, sw2 = conn.transmit(read)
        print(toHexString(data))
    else:
        print("Wrong key A")
```